# Renren for iOS SDK user permissions

Tags: objective-c, ios, post, sdk

Where or how to activate user permissions( such as uploading photos) to my application using Renren SDK for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register as a developer and also register your app at http://dev.renren.com/app . You will need someone on your team who can read Chinese, or be prepared to do a lot of cut-and-pasting into Google Translate. You will get an app key to use in your app, but it will only work with test accounts until RenRen is able to approve the app.